# Query doesn't just get specific id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query to get all logged activity on a folder.

The ID in this case is 2. I'm trying to get just records on 2, but as I have orwhere for search results, it gets all activity accross all folders for ths user.

Any idea how to fix this query?

```
$filtertext = $request->filter;
    $data = Activity::select('activity_log.*', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'activity_log.causer_id')
        ->where('subject_id', '=', $id)
        ->where('subject_type', '=', 'App\Models\Node')
        ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $filtertext . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $filtertext . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $filtertext . '%')
        ->with([
            'subject' => function ($q) {
                $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
            }
        ])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(12);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a group of `orwhere`'s in combination with normal `where`'s, you should put them in their own closure so the query builder knows these need to be seen together apart from the other `where`'s.

```
$filtertext = $request->filter;
$data = Activity::select('activity_log.*', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'activity_log.causer_id')
    ->where('subject_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('subject_type', '=', 'App\Models\Node')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($filtertext) {
        $query
            ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $filtertext . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $filtertext . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $filtertext . '%');
    })
    ->with([
        'subject' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
        }
    ])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(12);
```